# Reproducing Nest-function with recursive nesting does not work

Tags: function-construction, pure-function, iteration

In general, when I am learning a new programming language, it helps me to understand how builtin functions works. I am trying to reproduce the builtin `Nest[f,exp,n]` without any fancy Mathmatica functions.

This is what I want:

```
nesting[f_,k_] := Nest[f,#,k]&
=> nesting[f,3][Pi] = f[f[f[Pi]]]
```

I thought about implementing a recursive function:

```
nesting[f_,k_] := nesting[f,k-1]
nesting[f,1] := f[#]&
```

But unfortunately, this does not work. Trying to evaluate the function at some point does add this function evaluation to the outermost, not the innermost function.

```
=> nesting[f,3][Pi] = f[f[f[#1]&]]][Pi]
```

It seems that the ampersand (&) from the definition of a pure function has to be outside the whole nested function.
That means I want to have following structure:

```
nesting[f,3] = f[f[f[#1]]]&
```

For that I tried changing my function definition to

```
nesting[f_,k_] := nesting[f,k-1]&
nesting[f_,1] := f[#]
```

This yiedls a (atleast for me) unexpected and definitely unwanted behaviour:

```
nesting[f,3] = nesting[f,3-1]&
nesting[f,3][Pi] = nesting[f,2-1]&
```

Why does the second parameter (k) change depending on if I evaluate the function or just want to get the pure function from $3-1$ to $2-1$? And how can I fix my function in general?

Comment: First, you should note that there's an underscore missing in your code. ```nesting[f,1] := f[#]&``` Should have an underscore under the first f since it's a function argument. Without it the function only works with literally the symbol "f"

Comment: Thanks, I will edit that. It was actually a copy error, in Mathematica I implemented it with the underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few examples to play with:

```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, 1] := f;
nest[f_, k_] := f @* nest[f, k - 1];
```

First thing to note is that f and f[#]& are basically the same here. "f" is represents the function named "f". "f[#]&" represents "the function that you get if you apply f to some argument". Those are basically the same.

Here's a more confusing solution, which I think follows a bit more directly from what you're trying to do:

```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, 1] := f[#]&;
nest[f_, k_] := f[nest[f, k - 1][#]] &;
```

It's weird and gross. I'd find this very confusing. Maybe the best way to write this is to include all the arguments:

```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, 1][arg_] := f[arg];
nest[f_, k_][arg_] := nest[f, k - 1][f[arg]];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Searke Thank you for your quick answer! I am answering here because giving complex answers in comments is horrendously unreadable when you try to include code. Additionally to that, I need more then the few characters that are allowed in comments.

Unfortunately, it does not really solve my problem completely.

Let us begin with your first solution

```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, 1] := f;
nest[f_, k_] := f @* nest[f, k - 1];
```

That does work, but does not produce the wanted

```
nest[f_,3] = f[f[f[#]]]&
```

and also used the builtin Function "Composition".

Unfortunately, your solution

```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, 1] := f[#]&;
nest[f_, k_] := f[nest[f, k - 1][#]] &;
```

does not really work for me. The function will not be evaluated at some recursion point.

```
nest[f,k] = f[nest[f, 3 - 1][#1]] &
```

It seems to be the same problem as I was having before. Is there a problem on my part? It seems that the function does not have a pattern that it can match to because of the double double brackets and remains unevaluated?

Your solution

```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, 1][arg_] := f[arg];
nest[f_, k_][arg_] := nest[f, k - 1][f[arg]];
```

would work in principle but does not produce the wanted result

```
nest[f,3][Pi] = f[f[f[Pi]]]
nest[f,3] = nest[f,3]
```

Why will nest[f,3] not result in a pure function but remain unevaluated? Is there a way to archieve

To be clear:

I am trying to produce a pure function that expects one parameter, such that

```
nest[f,k] = f[f[f[.......f[f[f[#]]]......]]]&
```

that means, I want Mathmatica to return a pure function even when I am not evaluating at a certain point.

```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, 1][arg_] := f[arg];
nest[f_, k_][arg_] := nest[f, k - 1][f[arg]];
nest[f_, k_] := nest[f, k][#] &
```

This will result in

```
nest[f,3] = nest[f,3][#1]&
```

I am feeling that we are just there, how can I force Mathematica to evaluate the last

```
nest[f,3][#1]
```

to

```
f[f[f[#1]]]
```

?

**EDIT:**

As an example, when using the builtin "Nest"

```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, k_] := Evaluate[Nest[f, #, k]] &
```

I am getting

```
nest[f,3] = f[f[f[#1]]]&
```

This is the desired behaviour.

**EDIT2:**

Hey, I was able to solve the problem using nasty recursive pure functions:

`nest[f_,k_]:=Evaluate[If[#1==1, f[#2], f[#0[#1-1, #2]]] &[k, #]]&`

This leads to the expected behaviour:

`nest[f,3]=f[f[f[#1]]]&`

Comment: What are your go-to programming languages? This usually helps me understand where you're coming from. I gave you functions that were functionally equivalent to what you want. You're more interested in something different. Procedural code generation. Are you sure you really want to do this? I feel like you're inflicting brutal suffering on yourself unnecessarily.

Comment: "Function" has attribute HoldAll. So you want to do the evaluating outside of it. 
```
Clear@nest;
nest[f_, 1] := f[#] &;
nest[f_, k_] := 
 With[{inner = Apply[f[#] &, nest[f, k - 1]]}, Function@inner]
```

Comment: If you're coming from another functional programming language, there's a big caveat you should be aware of about "Functions" in Mathematica. They're more or less just patterns that behave like functions in different ways. Mathematica isn't a functional programming language. It's a loose implementation of one on top of a term rewriting system

Comment: Thank you for your informative answers! As I have stated in my post, I got it to work, but certainly not as elegant as you.

Comment: I am coming from an Python/C++ standpoint and I still have some trouble understanding Mathematicas "Pseuo" functional programming syntax.